# Let's get critical: Jan 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Beer Stack Exchange](http://beer.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 7 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Uh oh.  Usually the self-evaluation contains 10 questions.  Whatever the criteria are, it looks like we didn't have 10 that met them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why does Belgium have such a rich and profound brewing culture?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/why-does-belgium-have-such-a-rich-and-profound-brewing-culture)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What type of beer did the pilgrims have?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/what-type-of-beer-did-the-pilgrims-have)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a site (or app) like Beer Advocate that lets me give just an overall rating?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/is-there-a-site-or-app-like-beer-advocate-that-lets-me-give-just-an-overall-ra)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Beer Kit - How long is it good for](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/beer-kit-how-long-is-it-good-for)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to measure the caffeine content of a coffee beer at home?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/how-to-measure-the-caffeine-content-of-a-coffee-beer-at-home)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why is beer in Czech Republic so cheap?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/why-is-beer-in-czech-republic-so-cheap)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Beer-A-Day (Free Online) Calendars](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/beer-a-day-free-online-calendars)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---